# Cordova: Alternative of "Menu" button in Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working in **Phonegap/Cordova** and I need to use **menu** to go for app settings. But I have came to know that according to [Google/Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html), developer shouldn't use that menu button anymore. Instead, developer should use action bar for this purpose.

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), Android-powered devices are no longer required to provide a dedicated Menu button. With this change, Android apps should migrate away from a dependence on the traditional 6-item menu panel and instead provide an action bar to present common user actions.

But according to [cordova menu docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#menubutton), you can always call native menu. I am trying this, but it is not working at all. This is what I have tried:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
}

function onMenuKeyDown() {
        alert("Menu button pressed");
}
```

First of all, there is no **Menu** button in upcoming android devices, second, this code is not working at all. I haven't tested it on old devices, OS < 4.0.

Whats the possible alternate of menu button in phonegap? Should I use `ActionBar` for this purpose? And if it is so, should I have to write it for every platform?

This [link](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/160614/menu-button-on-nexus5) got some tricks, but all in vain.

There is a plugin for [android ActionBar for cordova](https://github.com/polychrom/cordova-android-actionbar), but question remains same, what I have to do with other platforms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you display the menu button in your HTML5 page?

Comment: Couldn't understand your point.

Comment: Instead of relying on if the device has a button, you could add your own button in the layout of your app and display your own menu when it's pressed. It is cross platform and requires no plugin.